# How can I read an imported object's code?

Tags: python

I don't know what attributes an object supports. How can I open up the module and figure out what's going on "under the hood"?

For example, I want to figure out what attributes the `datetime` object from the `datetime` module has in its `__init__`:

```
import datetime
curtime = datetime.datetime.now()
print(curtime[0])
```

But, since `datetime` has no `__getitem__` method, there must be a different way of accessing each part of the time (`day`, `month`, `year`, etc.)

I have found (by trial and error) that you can do this:

```
datetime.datetime.now().time()
datetime.datetime.now().date()
```

but I'm not sure what the proper name for what I'm doing here is, and how I can find other methods that belong to this object/class.

Comment: Read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)? Use [`help`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help) and [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir)? Go and look at [the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/datetime.py)?

Comment: Why on earth would you use "trial and error" to determine how to use `datetime`? The proper name for what you're doing here is "being silly"!

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about these. dir() in particular works very well. Do you know if there is a way to actually open up the module in an IDE so I can see what's going on? (I'm using Eclipse)

Comment: In PyCharm you can just keep hitting Cmd-B to get to the standard library definitions, not sure about Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your terminal, type `pydoc (whatever)` and you should be able to see all the variables and functions it has. If it's undocumented, `dir([whatever])` is the way to go. In any situation, obviously Google.
BTW, to clarify the terms in your question, `datetime` is a *module*. You have to understand modules, classes, and objects are different things. You can learn more about modules and the `dir()` function [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: Thanks Drew, although all the answers I got really helped, yours was great because that page really helped me with the terminology. Having the right words to Google is half the battle! (Maybe more than half...)

Comment: Could you help me understand what "primary and secondary prompts" mean, in the link you posted? (Under 6.2)

Comment: Ah okay. Glad you asked. The primary and secondary prompts mean the string used before you type something in your Python shell. So if you type `python` in your terminal, the default prompt looks like this: `>>>`. If you want to change the primary prompt, type `import sys` and then set `sys.ps1` to whatever prompt you like. (`C> ` for example)

Answer (score 0):

I find the `dir` function to be the most useful when dealing with unknown and undocumented objects ([`datetime` is well documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html), btw).

But if it weren't documented:

```
>>> import datetime
>>>
>>> dir(datetime)
['MAXYEAR', 'MINYEAR', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'date', 
'datetime', 'datetime_CAPI', 'time', 'timedelta', 'tzinfo']
>>> datetime.date
<type 'datetime.date'>
>>> dir(datetime.date)
['__add__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__',
'__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__',
'__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__radd__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__',
'__repr__', '__rsub__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__',
'__subclasshook__', 'ctime', 'day', 'fromordinal', 'fromtimestamp',
'isocalendar', 'isoformat', 'isoweekday', 'max', 'min', 'month', 'replace',
'resolution', 'strftime', 'timetuple', 'today', 'toordinal', 'weekday',
'year']
```

and so on...